# Using either isVisible ember logic or move this logic at the CSS level

Tags: ember.js

could anybody point in which specific use cases are using becameVisible and becameHidden events?

I have a case where i want to hide/show views depending on a specific state, and wondering if i should either move this logic at the CSS level via classNames or using isVisible Ember Logic.

The example below tried to show the current scenario.

```
Em.ContainerView.extend({

  childViews: ['image','spinner'],
  isLoading: true,

  image: Em.View.extend({
    classNames: ['product_image'],
    classNameBindings: ['isLoading'],
    isLoadingBinding: Em.Binding.oneWay('parentView.isLoading')

  }),

  spinner: Em.View.extend({
    classNames: ['spinner'],
    classNameBindings: ['isLoading'],
    isLoadingBinding: Em.Binding.oneWay('parentView.isLoading')
  })

})
```

CSS would be something like:

```
    > .product_image {
      display:block;
    }

    > .product_image.is-loading {
      display:none;
    }

    > .spinner {
      display:none;
    }

    > .spinner.is-loading {
      display:block;
    }
```

Any suggestions/comments on advantages/drawbacks of both scenarios would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way in the view template:

```
{{#unless content.isLoaded }}
  <div class='product_image is-loading'>....</div>
{{/unless }}
{{#if content.isLoaded }}
  <div class='product_image'>...</div>
{{/if }}
```